# Generate PDF from JPEGs in Separate Directories Grouped by Date/Name

Tags: python, powershell, pdf, jpeg

I am looking to generate a PDF report from JPEGs on a server. The JPEGs are in folders named after the location they were taken and the JPEGs are named based on the date they were taken (...\Location 1\15 08 03 description.jpg). Basically I need to grab all pictures taken at each site last month, group them evenly on a page (4 max/page), label the pages with location and date, export PDF.

I have written projects in Powershell and Python so it would be a lot easier for me to operate in these languages but I will consider all suggestions.

So far, my idea is to use switch/case to select the various folder names, for loop through to select all cases, and select all files with .jpg extension within a month range (maybe user prompted?). Where I fall flat is arranging the JPEGs into a PDF as I described.

Edit: So if you follow Mark Setchell's advice below, create the images he suggested and place them in C:\New folder. So suppose you had in this sub directory 3 folders (New folder, New folder (2), etc.) and 2 of these contain the nine colored JPEGS and the third is empty:

```
clear
$path="C:\New folder\"
$array=@()
$name="file*.jpg"
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter "New*")
{$i0=$path+$i; Get-ChildItem -path $i0 -Filter $name | ForEach-Object {$array+= $i0+"\"+$_.name}
montage $array -tile 2x2 -geometry +5+5 -title $i -page letter montage.pdf}`
```

My code overwrites the title on all pages with that of the 3rd empty folder. Also, it begins adding JPEGS from the next folder into the previous page, which should be titled as the previous folder and only contain those JPEGS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have 9 JPEG files in a directory, called `file1.jpg`...`file9.jpg` and they were created like this as lumps of red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow, black and gray.

```
convert -size 300x400 xc:red file1.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:lime file2.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:blue file3.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:cyan file4.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:magenta file5.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:yellow file6.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:black file7.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:gray40 file8.jpg
convert -size 300x400 xc:gray80 file9.jpg
```

If you now go into that directory and run the following `bash` script, it will montage the files into pages of A4 with 4 images on each page.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in file*jpg; do
    convert -label "$f" "$f" -depth 8 miff:-
done | montage -tile 2x2 -geometry +5+5 miff:- -page A4 montage.pdf
```

The crux of the matter is firstly adding a label to each image based on the filename and secondly sending the label and the image to a MIFF file which is capable of holding many images. The combined group of images are then fed into `montage` whch arranges them four to a page because of the `-tile 2x2`. The geometry sets the spacing between the pictures - bigger numbers mean bigger spaces. Finally we tell `montage` that the paper size is A4 and we want a PDF of all the input images - please!

Of course you can diddle with the background, the sizing, the spacing and the labelling till you are happy - but this should give you the basic idea.

You will get out a PDF called `montage.pdf` with these three pages:

**Page1**

[image]

**Page 2**

[image]

**Page 3**

[image]

Its shoud be fairly trivial to convert the loop to an ugly Windows-y `FOR` loop - [for loop help](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html).

Comment: this is perfect! Thank you. I do have a question, though. How would the script react if randomly some of the JPEGs were 400x300 mixed in with the 300x400?

Comment: Try it! It is an example of the technique, not necessarily a production-ready solution - you may need to adapt to your local conditions and requirements. If you have a problem, jjust ask another question - questions are free :-)

Comment: Okay, so this is working really well but I am having some trouble getting some particulars right. I need the title on each page to match the folder the pictures came from. Because of this, the pages must only be populated with images from the folders they came from. Currently my code fills empty spaces after each pass through and overwrites the titles with the last folder name. I'll post an edit above as my code is too long to fit here.

Comment: Sorry! I can't read that Powershell ? stuff, so it's hard to get a handle on what you are doing. Also I'm not sure why you are moving files around. I kind of expected your code to descend into one directory at a time and make a PDF from those files, then move into another directory and make another PDF. And maybe concatenate the PDFs at the end.

Comment: Yeah it is powershell. It's quick and dirty so I threw it together when I had a minute at work. I was trying to avoid creating unnecessary files in the creation of this so I don't clutter the folders. I suppose I could overwrite the old files every time or simply delete them all after concatenating. It appears imagemagick is not good for concatenating pdfs so I'll probably use pdftk.

Answer (score 1):

for converting your jpg's into pdf files you can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).
There are also different types of python [APIs](https://web.archive.org/web/20200822200503/https://imagemagick.org/script/api.php) for imagemagick, but in your case is the best to write a simple powershell script and execute imagemagick directly.

Just use the following imagemagick command:

`convert <yourfile.jpg> <newfile.pdf>`

Note: You **must** use file extentions in your command. Otherwise imagemagick don't know what todo.

Comment: Currently reading into this. Looking like montage is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `glob` to get the files (and then sort them if needed). I think the switch could get way too complicated.

As for the convert part: [Shibumi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32359601/3936732) answer.

Comment: I know how to use glob to grab similar files, but not sure how it could replace the switch/case to select the folders/directories. For example the folders are named in a scheme such as A1N, B2S, C18, R30, N37. Not much semblance of a pattern to loop through so switch/case is my best solution, thus far.

Comment: @MetalFever Is there something keeping you from just grabing everything? _That_ would make things a lot easier.

Comment: yes there are other folders in the directory that are not to be included in the report. Hence, the cases for the folders that are included. But I might be able to tag all the folders so I can glob them. I can't really change the structure too much without conferring with document control.

Comment: @MetalFever Oh, that's too bad. I somewhat asumed you can change the folder structure (eg. copy everything that goes into report to separate folder). IMO your structure sounds messy.